# Why is there an "Invalid literal error"?

Tags: python

I am getting the right answer in IDE but the online judge gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/editor_trsource_1410281976_804149.py", line 10, in 
    n=int(raw_input(''))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100 10'
```

Problem Link: http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/golf/minimal-combinatorial/

```
def fact(x):
    f=1
    while x>0:
        f=f*x
        x-=1
    return f
T=int(raw_input(''))
while T>0:
    n=int(raw_input(''))
    r=int(raw_input(''))
    ans=fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))
    print str(ans) + "\n"

    T-=1
```

Answer (score 6):

`n` and `r` are to be entered on the same line.

```
100 10
```

Your program expects them to be entered on two separate lines.

```
100
10
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @John Kugelman, your program expects n and r to be on the same line. You are better off using sys module to read the input. It would work like this:

```
import sys

def fact(x):
    f=1
    while x>0:
        f=f*x
        x-=1
    return f

T=int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())

while T>0:

    nr = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())
    #Or you can use nr directly while computing ans
    n = nr[0]
    r = nr[1]
    ans=fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))
    print str(ans) + "\n"

    T-=1
```

Sample Run:

```
$ python fact.py 
1  
5 2
10
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Still an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/editor_trsource_1410455624_65093.py", line 16, in 
    n = nr[0]
IndexError: list index out of range